# UISwitch adjustsImageWhenDisabled like UIButton?

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol, uiswitch

I'm creating an application that allows the user to add their own `UISwitch` and `UISegmentedControl` controls to the screen. Then they can Manipulate the colors, titles, etc. Though in order for me to 'select' them and manipulate them in my Development environment I need to set the user Interaction/enabled to NO.  Doing this causes the Controls to 'dim' and become a but transparent. I don't really want that as the Colors of the controls are also dim so the color representation is not correct.

the UIButton has an option: `@property(nonatomic) BOOL adjustsImageWhenDisabled`
I'd like something like this for  `UISwitch` and `UISegmentedControl`

Is there a way to make it so a disabled  `UISwitch` and `UISegmentedControl` is not 'dimmed' ?

Thanks,
   Scott<-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of.

However, you can solve this in a different way :)

Add a new transparent UIView over everything and use this to grab your touch events. This would let you keep your UIControls userInteractionEnabled set to YES but the touches would never reach them :)

Comment: Hmmm... Thanks, I'll have to see how much code that will take to make that happen.   Though I'm not sure how that works. I have a View that I place 3 Subviews on. Those views I've disabled user interaction and deal with Touch on the Base View. So it would seem like I need to either have or more SuperView and make my Existing base View OnTop and Transparent, or add a Transparent view on top of my 3 subviews and Pass the touches to the Base View.   I'm not sure how to Pass Gestures from one view to another.

Comment: Option (2) was the way I was thinking of doing it. And I'd grab touches by subclassing UIView yourself (perhaps calling it EventGrabberView) and implementing `touchesBegan:` in there. You can give your new EventGrabberView a delegate which would be your view controller and pass the touch events back that way.

Comment: I Added a Transparent View to the top of all of the Subviews. created an ivar for a handle to the view. Added the gestureRecognizers to Transparent view instead of base. Then Then I needed to actually use the control, I Disabled gesture recognition on the transparent view and moved that view to the back so the UIControl view was now on top.   The Gotcha was that I needed to add the new view in all of the routines that changed the shape,size,scale, etc of the views so that it would see the touch over the entire base view after the gestureRecognizer did its sizing/scaling